# Как узнать какие схемы относятся к tablespace

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Об оракле имею очень очень приблизительное представление.

Есть название тэйблспейса. Например test_tablespace. Ну и имя сервера известно тоже - test. Как составить запрос, показывающий, какие схемы относятся к указанному тейблспейсу и сколько занимают места?

Не гневайтесь, если в вопросе написал что-то не корректно.

Comment: Вы уже задавали подобный вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479867/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5  Вас не устроил ответ ? но ведь вы его приняли. Чем данный вопрос отличается от того ?

Comment: Там немного другое. По запросу получаем список тэйблспейсов и данные по ним - свободное место, занятое и т.д. А здесь - как получить список схем, относящихся к тейблспейсу и какое место использует каждая из них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tablespace_name,owner,TRUNC(sum(bytes)/1024/1024) Meg
  from dba_segments s
 where tablespace_name='test_tablespace'
 group by owner,tablespace_name
```

У меня есть подозрение, что имя tablespace должно быть большими буквами. По крайней мере у меня все большими, но может это я так их называю :)

Comment: Да, скорее всего Ваше подозрение оправдано)). У меня тоже большими, но по рассеянности написал маленькими. Спасибо Вам Mike!

Comment: Как я заметил, почти все(или даже все) объекты в системных таблицах названы большими буквами. Даже если при создании  написать маленькими.